# How to add the scrollbar for the div using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my scenerio. I have a div called `container` and inside that, there is another div called `draggable` and there is a scrollbar in it. So, in iPad, the scrollbar will not be visible, so we can write css for `-webkit-scrollbar`.

Yes, we can do like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11958657/4913153
But i want it in javascript

So, i want to add the css for the div using javascript only. I used this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555370/4913153, but its not working. Is there any way to add the scrollbar for the div in iPad using javascript only

This is my code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6rh0un0/)

Comment: I think, as you have already mentioned, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript) should work. Keep in mind, you need at least one stylesheet attached for this to work.

Comment: is there any other way of doing this without stylesheet?