# Get Scroll Bar elements in the Apps Script Code editor with a Chrome Content Extension

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

This question is about a Chrome Extension for the Apps Script code editor.

I've tried getting the scrollbar elements by className, but without success.  When I use the developer tools, to inspect the HTML in the Apps Script editor, I'm finding a name of `scrollbar-thumb`.  I assumed it was a className, but when I use `getElementsByClassName()` the code returns zero elements.

[image: Apps Script Scroll Bar]

I changed the color of the scroll bars from the developer tools to a magenta color, and it worked.

[image: MagentaScrollBars]

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Apps Script Scrollbar Color",
  "description": "This extension changes the scrollbar color",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "myIcon.png",
   "default_popup": "pop_up.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://script.google.com/*"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["pop_up.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ],

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

### Pop-up.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   //console.log('it ran');

    var scrollBarElements = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollbar-thumb');
    console.log('scrollBarElements.length: ' + scrollBarElements.length);

}, false);

});
```

### Dev Tools Screen:

[image: PopUpDevTools]

How can I get the scrollbar elements?

I can get the elements of the pop_up.html file, but I can't reference any HTML in the window itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can't select those [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb) directly with JS or in the dev console. 
No `document.getPseudoElementByName()` exists, so a function needs called to ultimately control the styling.

in dev console:
`function changeColor() { document.styleSheets[1].addRule("::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb", "background-color: pink;") };` >> enter

*taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555258/set-webkit-scrollbar-thumb-visibility-in-jquery)*

then run with `changeColor()` >> enter

Maybe include the [html] and [css] tags to see if anything different is offered from those groups

Comment: I don't understand the `styleSheets[1]` part.  What does that do?

Comment: references the css file in a script.google.com app, but not exactly sure how an extension can point to it

Comment: `document.styleSheets.length` returns zero.  The `styleSheets` property returns an object, but it looks like it's empty.  So, it looks like I'm at a "dead end" with that strategy.  So, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I can get elements by class name that show up in the dev console for the Apps Script editor, but they are all empty.  If I use:  `document.getElementsByClassName('code-area');`, it finds and returns an object, but it's empty.  I get `[object HTMLCollection]`, but the length is zero.

Comment: You're trying to select `.code-area` now or `::webkit-scrollbar-thumb`? Why marked as answer?

Comment: I'm trying different things, trying to understand what is going on.  The answer did help.  No-one else has tried to answer.  I still want to change the scrollbar color, but I want to be able to change the color of the background in the code editor also.  There's a broader issue.  I marked as correct, because it helped, and it is a legitimate answer.  I suppose marking it as correct might cause someone else to not review the question.  But anyone can answer, and I *could* change the correct answer to someone else's answer if I wanted/needed to.

Comment: ok, your extension changed the styling with that function though? if not, still may want to expose the question to the JS, html or css tags. I did see a length in regards to the `code-area` selection in dev console

Comment: Thanks.  I added the tags.  I have not been able to change any styling.  Removed the correct answer in case someone new takes a look.