# Can a PsuedoClass and Wildcard CSS be set using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Can all CSS be written using JavaScript? I'm having a hard time setting these two rules in JavaScript.

```
*{cursor:none!important}
html::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none!important}
```

Comment: Take a look at the second answer (by Chris) on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555258/set-webkit-scrollbar-thumb-visibility-in-jquery (note, it isn't a jquery answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set -webkit-scrollbar-thumb visibility in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555258/set-webkit-scrollbar-thumb-visibility-in-jquery)

Comment: One option would be to have multiple classes, and just use JS to assign the appropriate class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481485/changing-css-pseudo-element-styles-via-javascript)